# Update time using chrony from systemd script (some app restart)?

Tags: centos, systemd, chrony

if my hoster moves my VM to another host, the local time drifts away (up to 3 seconds). Chrony is able to fix this, but it takes a lot of time until it realizes. During this time, my database node (CockroachDB) shuts down because of the time difference (max 0.5 Sec allowed). Then, my systemd script restarts it.

Now I want the systemd script to first update the time for sure. So I added this to my  */etc/systemd/system/cockroach.service* script:

```
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/chronyc -a makestep
```

But this gives me error 501 (missing Authorization) because my systemd script runs as user "cockroach" and chrony daemon only accepts messages from users root or chrony (UDP).

Now I'm stuck. Is there a way to allow chrony to get messages from cockroach user, too? Or any other options to make it sync the time now (chrony is running, so no manual update possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is the "+" syntax for the *ExecStartPre* parameter. The following executes the *chronyc* executable with root permissions (+) and ignores any errors that may occur for this call (-):

```
ExecStartPre=-+/usr/bin/chronyc -a makestep
```

This worked fine for me.

You can find the documentation for these prefixes in the systemd documentation for the *ExecStart* parameter here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=